# How to make a bootstrap form where the label column fits the largest label?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

For example, when I make the label for `Password` too long, it goes outside the boundary of the column and isn't totally visible.

[Here's the CodeLab](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=horizontal-form-layout)

Is there any way to make a Bootstrap form that automatically sizes properly, based on the largest label size?

[image: Form Bootstrap]

Comment: This is what tables are for.

Comment: @Dellkan the internet told me that tables are stupid, for example [here](https://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)

Comment: Correct - which is because tables used to be abused to hell and back to create actual side-wide layout. Tables doesn't have a lot of good usage areas in html, but this are one of the few exceptions.

Comment: Normally you problem doesnt occur because at `xs` size you "stack" the columns on top of each other , at which point your label has all the room in the world, is their any reason why you wouldn't want the labels to have a mobile format ?

Comment: @MichaelColeman I don't understand where you got mobile format from. I just need to have rows of input, with the label on the left and the input on the right. When I pick a set column width for the label, sometimes there end up being labels that are a bit too long and get covered up by the input box

Comment: @Imray He mentioned mobile format because you've tagged twitter-bootstrap, which for most people are synonymous with attempting responsive-layout, i.e mobile-format.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using Javascript + Angular JS which dynamically changes the form column layout based on the number of characters in the password label.
You can change values as needed.

Here is a working **demo** - http://jsbin.com/kizupagira/1/edit?html,js,output

Im not sure what is generating labels, so the script would need to run the conditional check on number of chars in password field in order for form to be updated.

Comment: Using `col-X-Y` won't work for me since the columns don't expand when more text is added

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's creative. I wish there was a simpler way though, like in only CSS. In the meantime, I'll go with your suggestion since I'm using Angular already anyway

Answer (score 1):

I think that tables may not be necessary in this example. While a `<td>` in this case would provide the necessary responsiveness, you may still run into the same issue on very small screens: not enough room to display the longest label.

Here's how I would address this problem:

```
<br>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="bs-example">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Email</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
          <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" type="email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
          <input class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" type="password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-2 col-md-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-2">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-2 col-md-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-2">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you're screen get's to `xs` width, change the labels to float above the elements by changing the `<label>` from a `col-xs-2` to a `col-xs-12` and the `<input>` from a `col-xs-10` to a `col-xs-12`. I also added the other 3 sizes in the classes to provide you with even greater control over this layout.

Hope this provides some insight!

Here's a live example:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/axM8x9Bc51)

Answer (score 0):

you´re using `col-xs-2`. It have `width: 16.66666667%;`. So if you need resize this DIV, you need replace width value like:

```
<label for="inputPassword" style="width: initial;min-width: 16.66666667%;" class="control-label col-xs-2">PasswordPassword</label>
```

Or replace the style `col-xs_2` on bootstrapMod.css like:

```
.col-xs-2 {width: initial;min-width: 16.66666667%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yikes! Everyone on this thread needs to think about CSS classes...

**Answer:**

```
.control-label
{
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-all;

    /* Non standard for WebKit */
    word-break: break-word;

    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}
```